# removing numbers from a variable using php

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

The variable I am trying to remove the values from is called $order

for example  - $order is 485,894,1048,1040

I am trying to remove certain numbers which will vary each time these values are stored as $drinks_order

for example - $drinks_order is 1048,1040

So basically in the above example I wish to remove 1048 and 1040 from $order so I am then left with a new variable of $food_order which should be $food_order=485,894;

I have been trying this code but it doesn't seem to work properly

```
$nums = explode(',', $order);
$nums = array_diff($nums, array($drinks_order));
$food_order = implode(',', $nums);
```

Returns $food_order as 485,894,1048,1040

However when I test putting the actual numbers of $drinks_order in the code it removes them in the $food_order variable correctly

```
$nums = explode(',', $order);
$nums = array_diff($nums, array(1048,1040));
$food_order = implode(',', $nums);
```

Returns $food_order as 485,894

Comment: I don't understand. You said: `$food_order which should be $food_order=485,894;`, and then say that: `Returns $food_order as 485,894`. Isn't that the correct behaviour?

Comment: @BenM - in the case where it works he has an array as second argument, in the case where it does not work he has a string equal to `1048,1040`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$drinks_order = '1048,1040'; //must be a string
$nums = explode(',', $order);
$nums = array_diff($nums, explode(',', $drinks_order));
$food_order = implode(',', $nums);
```

Comment: @BenM , he has a syntax error, but he also exploded the string, so it is not identical.

Comment: Fixed syntax error, and it is not the same code. He is converting a string into an array, that will return `array([0] => '1048,1040')`, its not exploding on the comma.